# One or more browsers which are configured in the project's Browserslist

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic framework:

While starting the ionic application getting the following warnings. Please suggest the fix:

```
[ng] One or more browsers which are configured in the project's Browserslist configuration will be ignored as ES5 output is not supported by the Angular CLI.
[ng] Ignored browsers: chrome 60
[ng] - Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...
[ng]     TypeScript compiler options "target" and "useDefineForClassFields" are set to "ES2022" and "false" respectively by the Angular CLI. To control ECMA version and features use the Browerslist configuration. For more information, see https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-browser-compatibility
```

Thanks in advance.

My `.browserslistrc` have the following entries:

```
Chrome >=60
Firefox >=63
Edge >=79
Safari >=13
iOS >=13
```

Comment: Why do you have chrome 60 in the browser list?

Comment: thanks @Konrad, updated the .browserslistrc file entries in the answer, do I need to update it?

Comment: Yes, definitely, chrome 60 is 5 years old

Comment: @Konrad please share the desired list in an answer.

Comment: Latest stable versions

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For my Angular 15 projects I use the [recommended config](https://v15.angular.io/guide/build#configuring-browser-compatibility):

```
last 2 Chrome versions
last 1 Firefox version
last 2 Edge major versions
last 2 Safari major versions
last 2 iOS major versions
Firefox ESR
```

Answer (score 7):

Add **`defaults`**, increase audience coverage of 46.8 % to 94.4 %

```
defaults
Chrome >=60
Firefox >=63
Edge >=79
Safari >=13
iOS >=13
```

[image]

See more:
https://browsersl.ist/

Answer (score 6):

Angular 15, which you are probably using, does not support compiling to **ES5** format. In the file `.browsersllist.rc` you specify the version of the browser you want to support.

Since Chrome 60 does not fully support **ES6** (according to https://browsersl.ist/) and Angular is unable to compile to **ES5**, this specific version of the browser is ignored. If you upgrade your Chrome version to 61, i.e. `Chrome >= 61` this warning should disappear.

Comment: It does not work and I have the latest Chrome

Answer (score 5):

Thanks Konrad... it works for me

```
Chrome >=99
Firefox >=99
Edge >=79
Safari >=13
iOS >=13
```

Answer (score 1):

you could add this to your .browserlist.rc:

```
supports es6-module
```

these are all versions that support JavaScript modules via script tag